# Creating star pattern but if even add 1 space in C

Tags: c

i made a star pattern but it doesn't work as expected
how to make pattern like this?

```
**********
 **********
**********
 **********
**********
 **********
**********
 **********
**********
 **********
```

square star pattern but on even lines increments 1 space
but on the next line back to normal

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int n;
int i;
int j;
printf("Add rows :");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
            printf(" ");
        else
            printf("*");
    }
    /* Print stars after spaces */
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Test in a debugger. Work through the code on paper.

Comment: Tip: Declare your variables inside your `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; ...)` instead of pre-declaring them in a jumble up top.

Comment: On even lines print a space, else *don't do anything* (i.e. don't even have an `else` clause). Then print the stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    int i;
    int j;
    printf("Add rows :");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1)
                printf(" ");

        /* Print stars after spaces */
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This code works correctly for me. I just moved the place for some code blocks. Instead of inserting multiple whitespaces, you should insert it only once and insert n times stars in any case.
Output:

```
Add rows :6
******
 ******
******
 ******
******
 ******
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make pattern like the picture:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int n;
int i;
int j;
printf("Add rows :");
scanf("%d", &n);
//outer loop for checking odd or even line
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 1)
        printf(" ");
    // inner loop for adding stars according to input
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is, instead of thinking about the problem as "printing a space or not, then the stars", is notice that the "space-less lines" are simply the other lines starting from the second character. In C, strings are represented as arrays of characters (terminated by `'\0'`). This means that, you can store both types of lines at once by storing those starting with a space:

```
stars = " **********";  // '\0' is implicitly appended
```

then, the "space-less string" simply is `&stars[1]` (or, similarly, `stars + 1`).

From here, you obtain the expected behaviour from unconditional code where only the *data* passed to the code changes *i.e.* you only have **one** `printf` call:

```
const char *line = (i % 2 ? stars : &stars[1]);
printf("%s\n", line);
```

which is even better expressed by using [`puts`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) (which automatically prints the `'\n'`):

```
int main()
{
    static const char * const stars = " **********";
    unsigned line_count;

    printf("Add rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &line_count);

    for (unsigned line = 0; line < line_count; line++)
        puts(line % 2 ? stars : &stars[1]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```